# Run MS Word Macros via Java code

Tags: java, ms-word

Can anyone please let me know what is the correct syntax to execute a MS Word Macro in Java. I tried below but it's throwing error:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE  BatchConvertDocToPDF /w /m");
```

where `BatchConvertDocToPDF` is the name of the macro.

When I run the code, it tries to look for a `.doc` file with name `BatchConvertDocToPDF`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*… but it's throwing error*" So which error is it?

Comment: Since you're working with Java the VBA tags in your question are inappropriate.

Comment: I finally got my code running. There was some syntax error. The correct syntax is 

Process process = rt.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE /w /mBatchConvertDocToPDF");

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct commandline switch - `/m` - but the wrong commandline syntax. The macro name needs to immediately follow the switch, with no space. Putting it before doesn't work.

On the other hand, the name of the document containing the macro needs to be in the position where you've put the macro name. And in order to use this command line you MUST be opening a document. The command line cannot be used to simply run a macro in Word - no functionality of this type exists. So the correct commandline would be:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE PathAndFileNameWithMacro.docm /w /mBatchConvertDocToPDF"
```

If Java can automate the Word interop then what you need in order to run a macro in an already opened document is the Word.Application.Run method. That would be something like this (code is C#):

```
wdApp.Run("'C:\\Test\\DocWithMacroForInteropAppRun.docm'!Test");
```

If you look at the object model Help topic you'll see that the path to the file name (or just the file name) is not strictly required, but results are more predictable (it's more likely to work) if you use it.

For the sake of completeness, a list of the valid command line switches in Word follows, take from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210565/how-to-use-startup-command-line-switches-to-start-word-2010--word-2007

**List of Word startup switches**
The following Word startup (command-line) switches are listed in Word Help.

- /a Starts Word and prevents add-ins and global templates (including
  the Normal template) from being loaded automatically.

  The /a switch also locks the setting files; that is, the setting
  files cannot be read or modified if you use this switch.
- /laddin_path Starts Word and then loads a specific Word add-in.
- /m Starts a new instance of Word without running any AutoExec macros.
- /mmacro_name  Starts Word and then runs a specific macro. The /m
  switch also prevents Word from running any AutoExec macros.
- /n   Starts a new instance of Word with no document open. Documents opened
  in each instance of Word will not appear as choices in the Window
  menu of other instances.
- /safe Starts Word in Safe Mode.
- /ttemplate_name Starts Word with a new document based on a template
  other than the Normal template.
- /w Starts a new instance of Word with a blank document. Documents opened in each instance of Word will not appear as choices in the Window menu of the other instances.
- (no switch)  A new Word window is opened with a blank document using
  the existing instance of the Word program.

The following Word startup (command-line) switches are not listed in Word Help.

- /c Starts a new instance of Word and then invokes NetMeeting.
- /q   Starts Word without displaying the Word splash screen.
- /r Starts Word, starts Setup, makes changes in the Windows registry, and then quits. This switch forces a re-register of Word in the Windows registry.
- /u Has no effect and does not start Word.
- /x Starts a new instance of Word from the operating shell (for example, to print in Word). This instance of Word responds to only one DDE request and ignores all other DDE requests and multi-instances. If you are starting a new instance of Word in the operating environment (for  example, in Windows), it is recommended that you use the /w switch, which starts a fully functioning instance.
- /z This is similar to the /t switch. However, this switch raises the New event. For example: winword.exe /z mytemplate.dot.
- pathname\file_name Starts Word with a specific document open.

  Note: To open multiple files at once, use pathname\filename.

  Example: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe"
  c:\filename1.doc c:\filename2.doc
- (any other switch) Starts a new instance of Word. For example, if you start Word with just the / and no switch, or with any unlisted switch combination, Word just starts a new instance of Word with a new blank document.
- /ffile_name Starts Word with a new document based on
  an existing file.
- /h http:// file_name Starts Word and opens a
  read-only copy of a document that is stored on a Microsoft Windows
  SharePoint Services site. The site must be on a computer that is
  running Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 or Windows
  SharePoint Services 2.0.
- /t file_name Starts Word and opens an existing file.
- /pxslt_name Starts Word and opens an existing XML
  document based on the specified Extensible Stylesheet Language
  Transformation (XSLT).  Note XSLT: A file that 'used to transform XML
  documents into other types of documents, such as HTML or XML. It is
  designed for use as part of XSL.